# 3D like effect on text - reverse engineering

Tags: text, 3d

I have a text (see picture below) with the "Adobe Caslon Pro" font type, and some sort of slight 3D effect added to it. 
I would like to ask you for help to identify how this 3D effect on the text was made.
Please suggest a method to recreate it.

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Just my 2 cents here: **don't do that**.  It looks awful and cheap. It's a very outdated look and will only make people think the design is old or the designer is bad/lazy

Comment: Needs more drop shadow...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How would you make it look better? I am open to any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a **Bevel and Emboss** layer style using **Photoshop**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes this looks very much like what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Bevel and Emboss, in Photoshop. If you don't have Photoshop, there's likely a WordArt in Office Word that looks similar to this.